# New environment error (question)

Tags: environments

I'm trying to make a "custom" environment for my document, here's what i got

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{01}{RGB}{0,95,200}
\newenvironment{custom}[2]{{\medskip\noindent\bf\color{01} #1}\\{\it #2 }}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{custom}{Observation}
$x\in Z(G)$ si y solo si $xy=yx$, para todo $y\in G$ si y solo si $N(x)=G$, si y solo si \[\frac{o(G)}{o(N(x))}=1=|[x]|.\]
\end{custom}

\end{document}
```

which had no problems, but in this case, since the text starts with a "$" symbol, i get an error,

> Extra }, or forgotten $. [$] Missing } inserted. [\end{custom}]

Which i can avoid by putting everything on {} like

```
\begin{custom}{a}
{b}
\end{custom}
```

But I was wondering if there is a way I can modify the `\newenvironment` to make it work without having to make any changes, thanks in advance.

Comment: `\bf` and `\it` are  outdated commands, but that's not the cause of your problem: You define with 2 arguments but provide only one, the second tries to read `$`, getting you into troubles

Comment: what is the optimal or more up to date command for bold letters?

Comment: and how do i fix the arguments? i'm quite lost there, i think it was fine in the arguments

Comment: I've posted a possible answer, but I think you should use a `theorem` like environment rather than a `\newenvironment` here

Comment: oh, i wanted to, but i'll try to make some similar ones but with boxes, so i think this was the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand, the environment body text should be typeset with `\it` (of course better with `\itshape`), so it is not the second argument `#2` here, which is not needed.

In the given example of the O.P., there is no 2nd argument given, so LaTeX tries to read the `$` from the body leading into errors.

Use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf` and `\textcolor{01}{#1}` rather than `\color{01} #1`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{01}{RGB}{0,95,200}
\newenvironment{custom}[1]{{\medskip\noindent\bfseries\textcolor{01}{#1}}%

\itshape  }{%End code -- empty here
}

\begin{document}

\begin{custom}{Observation}
$x\in Z(G)$ si y solo si $xy=yx$, para todo $y\in G$ si y solo si $N(x)=G$, si y solo si \[\frac{o(G)}{o(N(x))}=1=|[x]|.\]
\end{custom}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No comments on the math typesetting please -- that's not the core of the question ;-)